# Why is YouTube audio on phones (not restricted to iPhones) garbled?

Tags: youtube, html5-video, mp4, ogg, webm

EDIT: I have tried using several different audio codecs via HandBrake, each produces the same result.

EDIT: We've experimented with the audio and we've discovered that wearing ear buds or headphones on the mobile device makes the problem appear to disappear. Obviously something is incorrect with the recorded audio (stereo) where the mobile phones, via their speakers, are expecting mono. Is forcing stereo to mono during the conversion process causing the problem? More research ensues.

I am stumped and have banged my head against the wall for 2 days now trying to figure this out. We posted a video on our companies website that works well on all devices except for mobile phone devices including iPhone and Samsung. On those devices the video will play, but the audio is garbled beyond use. Here is the link to the video -

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IVHv6nG20M&list=UUKTqrRWGA_rcxOYVVocB9kg

I have also used the .mp4, .ogv, and .webm versions of the file on our website and the result is the same on phones. Here is the URL where the video is being used -

http://www.apexinnovations.com/miRULE.html

I have tried converting to different video types using Miro Video Converter, uploading and testing all the while. The results are the same - works well on all devices save for phones. I have also exported the video to YouTube using iMovie and still I have the same results.

The kicker? The other two videos on our YouTube channel and on our website play just fine on every device. There was no difference in the way that I output or converted or uploaded those files.

Has anyone else ever had this experience? What could I be doing wrong to make this happen? Is there a fix for it?

Thank you very much for any insight that you may have!

Comment: Which audio codecs are you using for the mp4/ogv and webm videos?

Comment: MPEG-4 HE ACC at48kHz in mono with 'normal' quality.

Comment: For those of you who voted to close this post - where would this post be better asked?

Comment: @JayBlanchard maybe http://webapps.stackexchange.com/, I guess...

Comment: @JayBlanchard Did you ever find an answer to this?  I am running across the exact same symptoms and cleaning up the sound and reuploading doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @Kevin - Not exactly. We changed all of the recordings to mono, which fixed any phase cancellation that was happening. I have gotten away from doing the videos though and really have not studied what was going on any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you encode your audio or video. Youtube will re-encode it anyway. Or have you ever seen a video on youtube that you would have no sound or picture for? This would not be possible with 7bln people in the world uploading videos directly from their camcorders.

On the top of that, youtube will adapt the bitrate to suit your connection speed. So with a phone with bad GPRS connection it might sound garbled, while on the same phone connected to wifi, it might sound just fine. This is both for user experience but mostly to conserve bandwidth.

You can see their guidelines here: https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1722171&topic=1728573&parent=1728585&rd=1

But they will ultimately re-encode it anyway.

Comment: I understand that they will re-encode it - but I have the vids straight up on our website and have no issues with 2 of them, just the one video. I am connected to the web via wifi and have tested the video from multiple connections with multiple devices. This is happening on both the YouTube vid and the website vid for just this one video.

Comment: By the way, I noticed having the HQ option on, it doesn't have very garbled sound. On the HQ version, however, I can hear 'noise' in the sound. Do you have a noice reduction option in your audio encoder. The youtube encoder for the non-HQ version might mistakenly take this noise as the real sound and optimize the speech away. This is just a wild guess but might help.